# Modeling user for distance queries

Tags: django, postgresql, geolocation, django-geoposition

We want to be able to query local sellers based on seller's preferred distance to a geolocation set by a customer using PostgreSQL and Django models.

Our seller model is given below:

```
class Seller(AbstractModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField('users.User')
    distance = models.IntegerField()
    geoposition = GeopositionField()
```

For example:
Seller John can travel 50 miles. If buyer's location(lat, long) is 49 miles a John's geoposition, we get John.

Comment: Postgis is probably the best way to do queries of this type within postgres? Do you have any reasons not to use postgis?

Comment: I don't have any experience with postgis. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Any ideas how that would work with postgis?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can write a solutions with just postgreSQL.

Try filtering the query using a distance calculation between the buyer and seller location and compare that to the sellers preferred distance.

It appears you want a arithmetic query correct? I think the above example will help you ask me and the community with more questions.